# PouchDB for Chrome Apps

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, indexeddb, pouchdb

I'm making a Chrome App and using PouchDB(all my first time). Got the IndexedDB running on the Resources panel of the DevTools. The problem is the adding and updating of data to PouchDB. It's not working.

[image: IndexedDB]

Here's the code: (app_jr.js)

```
var saveregister, JrRegisterObj, pn;

JrRegisterObj = function (databasename, remoteorigin){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(this, 'pdb', {writable:true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'remote', {writable:true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'formobject', {writable:true});
Object.defineProperty(this, 'errordialog', {writable: true});

this.pdb = new PouchDB(databasename);
this.remote = remoteorigin + '/'+databasename;

};

saveregister = function(event) {
var n = {};

if(!this.formobject._id.value){
    n._id = new Date().getTime() + '';
} else {
    n._id = this.formobject._id.value;
}

n.jr_u_ubn = (this.formobject.jr_u_ubn.value === '') ? '' :    this.formobject.jr_u_ubn.value;
n.jr_u_name = (this.formobject.jr_u_name.value === '') ? '' : this.formobject.jr_u_name.value;
n.jr_u_branch = (this.formobject.jr_u_branch.value === '') ? '' : this.formobject.jr_u_branch.value;

this.pdb.put(n, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
    } else if(response && response.ok){

    }
});
}

pn = new JrRegisterObj('jr_register');

pn.formobject = document.getElementById('jr_reg_form');
pn.errordialog  = document.getElementById('errordialog');

pn.formobject.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
e.preventDefault();
pn.saveregister();
});
```

For the html file:(junior-register.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" manifest="jr_register.manifest">
<head>
<title>Junior Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
  <h1>Junior Register</h1>
</div>
<section id = "add_jr">
<form class="pure-form" id = "jr_reg_form" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register</legend>
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <input type="hidden" id="_rev" name="_rev" value="">
        <input type="hidden" id="_id"  name="_id" value="">
        <td>UBN:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="jr_u_ubn" name_u="jr_u_ubn"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="jr_u_name" name="jr_u_name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Branch:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="jr_u_branch" name="jr_u_branch"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="jr_register_btn" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Register</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app_jr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pouchdb-nightly.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pouchdb.mapreduce.noeval.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jr-register.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I got help from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/building-offline-first-app-pouchdb/)

I really exert effort on researching for this, but I can't find a solution. I'll greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I answered my own question..(app.js)

```
var pdb = new PouchDB('pouchjrreg');

var form, savenote;

form = document.getElementById('jrregform');

savenote = function(event){
var o ={};

o.jr_u_ubn = form.jr_u_ubn.value;
o.jr_u_name = form.jr_u_name.value;
o.jr_u_branch = form.jr_u_branch.value;

if(event.target._id.value == ''){
o._id = new Date().getTime() + '';
} else {
o._id = event.target._id.value;
}

pdb.put(o, function(error, response){
if(error) {
  console.log(error);
  return;
} else if(response && response.ok){

}
});
}

form.addEventListener('submit', savenote);
```

It works now!
And some updates for the html file.